# any faster way to get the minimum col for a dynamic range in excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, automation, openpyxl

I am an absolute noobie in python and even more so in excel automation, please advise how can I get the min_col based on a user-specific column range, instead of the entire workbook?

Background:
I have an extracted report whereby I need to find the "Header Row" aka Table Header.

The report output consist of the report parameters at the top in Column A and Column B, then the table data will begin. The header row in this will case row 3.

To illustrate:

```
| Company: | ABC       |
| Period:  | June 2022 |
| Company  | Period    | Customer | Customer Category | Journal Memo | Amount |
| ABC      | June 2022 | DEF      | External          | def          | 123.45 |
| ABC      | June 2022 | EFG      | External          | efg          | 987.65 |
```

Using ws.min_col will return 1.

Therefore, I found the Header Row in another way:

```
headerRow = 0
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=3,max_col=3, max_row=30):          
    for cell in row:            
        if cell.value == None:
            headerRow = cell.row +1
```

The above code successfully returned 3 to me. However, I find that I may be missing something and there could possibly be a faster way to get the header row without using iter/loop?

Please advise,
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand from the description what you want to check.

Comment: I need to identify what is the "Header Row". In this case, Row 3 will be my "Header Row". How can I do it faster instead of using loop/iter_row method?

Comment: How do you want to determine what the header is? Your current code just looks for cells with no value.